# I don't understand this error message A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')). What should I do?

Tags: kotlin, types, return

I am trying to compile this code in Kotlin but I keep on getting this error message "A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}'" Can anyone let me know what is the problem?

```
abstract class SentenceVerifier(private var subject: String, private var verb: String, private var objectt: String,) {
   
   abstract val resourse1: String
   abstract val resourse2: String 
   abstract val resourse3: String 
   
    
   fun isSentenceStructureCorrect(): String {
         if (subject == resourse1) {
           println("Great job! You're correct!")
       } else {
           println("Sorry, that's not correct. Try again.")
       }
       if (verb == resourse2) {
           println("Great job! You're correct!")
       } else {
           println("Sorry, that's not correct. Try again.")
       }
       if (objectt == resourse3) {
           println("Great job! You're correct!")
       } else {
           println("Sorry, that's not correct. Try again.")
       }
   }  
    
}
```

Comment: Your function is supposed to return a string. Instead, you are simply printing one. Either make the return type `Unit` or use `return` instead of `println`.

Comment: Hello my friend. That's great advice. I changed the return type to Unit and it worked perfectly. Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the error message:

> "A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body"

A "function with a block body" that returns a `String` has the following form:

```
fun foo(): String {
  // block body returning something
  return "something"
}
```

A function with a block body with no return value looks like this:

```
fun foo() {
  // block body doing something
  println("something")
}
```

For completeness, a function with an expression body has the following form:

```
fun foo(): String = "something"
```

Your function clearly has a "block body".

The first part of the error message was:

> A 'return' expression required

This should be read literally: you need a `return` in your function to actually return something, since it defines a `String` as its result.